# java.lang.NullPointerException: Java Beginner

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Hi Guys sorry i'm ridiculously new to this but I'm attempting to read in a file and place into an array to work out the averages of the data in there, This is my code but every time i'm getting a NullException on "  String[] row = file.readLine().split(" ");"

```
int nRows =652; 
int nCols =7;

double data [][] = new double[nRows][nCols];
char map [][]  = new char[nRows][nCols];

for (int i=1; i < nRows ; i++) {

    String[] row = file.readLine().split(" ");
    // below here ......
    for (int j=1; j < nCols-1 ; j++) {
        data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(row[j]); 
        //put if no more data then stop.        
    }
}

file.close();

for (int i =0; i < nRows; i++) { 
    for (int j=0; j< nCols; j++) { 
       map[i][j] = '0'; 

    }
}

for (int i =1; i < (nRows -1); i++) { 
    for (int j=1; j < (nCols -1); j++) {

       double sum = data [i-1] [j] + data [i] [j-1] + data [i][j+1] + data [i+1][j];
       double average = sum /4;
       System.out.println(average);
    }
}

for (int i=0; i <nRows; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j <nCols; j++) {
       System.out.print(map [i][j] + "");
    }



for (int h = 1; h < (nRows -1); h++) {
    for (int l =1; (l <nCols -1); l++) {

          double sum = data [h-1] [h] + data [i] [h-1] + data [i] [h+1] + data [i+1] [h]; 
         // this is average.
         double average = sum /4;
         System.out.println(average);

    }
}
}

for (int i=0; i <nRows; i++) {
 for (int j=0; j <nCols; j++) {
     System.out.print(map [i][j] + " ");
 }
 System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Comment: you're trying to read an empty line by the sounds of it.

Comment: Where is your `file` object created?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have less than 652 lines. file.readLine() returns null when there is no more line to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use your debugger and check the variable 'file'. NullPointerException will be thrown when your variable is null and you try to call function from the null variable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're calling

```
file.readLine().split()
```

after the end of the file, so file.readLine() is null.

You could wrap the line in a null check - something like the following:

```
String[] row;
String[] rawRow = file.readLine();
if (rawRow != null) {
    row = rawRow.split(" ");
} else {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created the `file`correctly, the method `readline()`returns null when end of file is reached, see documentation [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

You can always check if the return is not null:

```
    for (int i=1; i < nRows ; i++) {

      String line = file.readLine();
      if(line!=null){
        String[] row = file.readLine().split(" ");
        // below here ......
        for (int j=1; j < nCols-1 ; j++) {
            data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(row[j]); 
            //put if no more data then stop.
         }
       }
     ...
   }
```